# Match foo or bar vim regex

Tags: regex, vim

Is there a method of matching multiple words at once in a `vim` search-and-replace? Something like:

```
:%s/foo|bar//g
```

to search for `foo` or `bar` and replace with nothing (this searches for the pattern `foo|bar`, which isn't what I want). I can search for multiple *characters* this way:

```
abcdef
:%s/[ace]//g
```

results in:

```
bdf
```

Can I do the same thing with words?

I'm well aware I could do this like this:

```
:%s/foo//g
:%s/bar//g
```

I'm looking for a one-line solution, if such a thing exists.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In vim regexes, the alternation operator needs to be escaped with a backslash: use `foo\|bar`.

Answer (score 11):

Instead of escaping `|` with a backslash, you can use vim's ["very magic" mode](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Simplifying_regular_expressions_using_magic_and_no-magic) with the `\v` sequence:

```
:%s/\vfoo|bar//g
```