# How to filter text with multiple keyword in vim

Tags: vim, text, filter

**Question is**:

To display only lines contains **keyword1** or **keyword2**,how to do that?

I know there's command like **:g/pattern** but that can work only for one keyword.

It's not duplicate question as it is to search instead of search replace case

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003055/match-foo-or-bar-vim-regex

Answer (score 1):

Use alternation:

```
:g/foo\|bar\|baz/#
```